# Clarification over Scala polymorphism

Tags: scala, oop, polymorphism

On a recent worksheet I was presented with the question asking what would be the output of the following code:

```
class A { def m(x:Double) = x+x }
class B[Any] extends A{ def m(x: Any) = print(x) }
class C[Any] { def m (x:Double) = x+x; def m (x: Any) = print(x) }
val obj1 = new B[Int]; val obj2 = new C[Any]
obj1.m(1); obj1.m(2.3); obj2.m(4); obj2.m(5.6)
```

I'm quite confused as to what having a concrete type in the square brackets after the class name would mean (i.e. `class B[Any]`). Is the later expression `val obj1 = new B[Int]` valid because `Int <: Any`, Int being a subclass of Any?

When later running the code snippet, the result given was simply "1" being printed. This was not what I had expected the call to `obj.m(2.3)` to resolve at `def m(x: any)`, where it seems in actuality the compiler went up to A and called the `m` in `class A`.

The later expressions, `obj2.m(4)` and `obj2.m(5.6)` seems to make sense as both 4 and 5.6 would land in the function with `def m(x: Double)`, thus not print anything out.

In what order exactly does the compiler traverse to find what to call? I'd be very grateful if someone could clear up my confusions with how polymorphism is handled here by Scala, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `class B[Any]`, you define a class with a type parameter called `Any`. Don't confuse the type parameter name with the actual class `Any`. You are just shadowing its name.

You could just as fine do this:

```
class B[Int]
val obj = new B[String]
```

You may see why it is bad practice to name type parameters after actual types. Usually, people use single letter names for their type parameters, like this:

```
class B[T] // I just changed the name of the type parameter from "Int" to "T".
val obj = new B[String]
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. That makes a whole lot of sense now - what a devious question :)

Comment: Oh, one more thing - does the Any inside the function parameters in this case act like "T" or does it refer to the actual type Any?

I couldn't accept it back then as there was a time limit

Comment: It acts like `T`. The actual type `Any` is shadowed.